# SQL Server Query with join and merge two row into single row of record

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, merge

I have had a sample table like these

[image]

[image]

I would like to have a final result for my query in this way

[image]

I have no clue how to create SQL Server Query to archive the result as said about. Would you mind to guide me how to make it works?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have at most two rows, you can use `row_number()` to enumerate the values and conditional aggregation (or pivot, if you prefer):

```
select m.movementid, m.arrflt, m.depflt,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then des else 0 end) as des_1,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then cargo else 0 end) as cargo_1,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then mail else 0 end) as mail_1,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then luggage else 0 end) as luggage_1,
       sum(case when seqnum = 2 then des else 0 end) as des_2,
       sum(case when seqnum = 2 then cargo else 0 end) as cargo_2,
       sum(case when seqnum = 2 then mail else 0 end) as mail_2,
       sum(case when seqnum = 2 then luggage else 0 end) as luggage_2
from movement m join
     (select md.*,
             row_number() over (partition by movementid order by movementid) as seqnum
      from movementdetail md
     ) md
     on md.movementid = m.movementid
group by m.movementid, m.arrflt, m.depflt;
```